# How do I write a list using BinaryWriter?

Tags: c#, binarywriter

I want to use a generic WriteList(List value) function to write a List using the BinaryWriter. Here is the code I am using:

```
public void WriteList<T>(List<T> value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < value.Count; i++)
    {
        _writer.Write(value[i]);
    }
}
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
 Error  1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write(bool)' has some invalid arguments    
Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'T' to 'bool'
```

The BinaryFormatter is absolutely **not** an option.

Comment: any constraint on T? like T:struct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check out the docs for [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) you'll see it doesnt accept an argument of object (*Writes primitive types*), and the compiler is trying its best at an overload, and failing, since you can't cast your T to bool, or anything else that BinarwWriter would like.

You're going to have to convert your object into something the BinaryWriter will work with.

Comment: Such as... using reflection to get all the value-type members of the class, and then writing them one after another with BinaryWriter.  I consider this a part of your answer though, since it's about the only place you could go with it.

Comment: yea, but who'd want to. you could also run into issues if you had a value type(struct) with a reference type as a member. If you really wanted to do something, you could implement a custom serializer to output as byte[] or string etc. would want a real good reason to do this imo.

Comment: Seriously!  The only good reason I've ever found is because you want a BinaryFormatter in Silverlight.

Answer (score 6):

I really don't think you can avoid BinaryFormatter. Because type T can be any complex type and each instance of T can represent a huge graph of variables on memory.

so the only solution you have is to convert your instance of T to the byte[] format and the simplest solution for that is: BinaryFormatter

Actually the reason .Write() method only accept primitive types is that it knows how to convert them directly to byte[] (using Convert.ToXXX()) but there is no way it could guess that for generic type T.

As a work around you can define an interface like this:

```
public interface IBinarySerializable
{
    byte[] GetBytes();
}
```

and then implement it in your class:

```
public class MyClass: IBinarySerializable
{
    public int X {get;set;}
    public byte[] GetBytes()
    {
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(X); // and anyother
    }
}
```

and change your method to this:

```
public void WriteList<T>(List<T> value) where T:IBinarySerializable
{
    for (int i = 0; i < value.Count; i++)
    {
        _writer.Write(value[i].GetBytes());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't pass a generic T to BinaryWriter.Write - it has overloads for many specific types (bool, byte, byte[], int, string, etc), but no generic one. So you'll need to do it yourself, in some way similar to the code below.

```
    public void WriteList<T>(List<T> value)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < value.Count; i++)
        {
            switch (Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(T))){
            //_writer.Write(value[i]);
                case TypeCode.Boolean:
                    _writer.Write((bool)(object)value[i]);
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Byte:
                    _writer.Write((byte)(object)value[i]);
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Char:
                    _writer.Write((char)(object)value[i]);
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Decimal:
                    _writer.Write((decimal)(object)value[i]);
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Double:
                    _writer.Write((double)(object)value[i]);
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Single:
                    _writer.Write((float)(object)value[i]);
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Int16:
                    _writer.Write((short)(object)value[i]);
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Int32:
                    _writer.Write((int)(object)value[i]);
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Int64:
                    _writer.Write((short)(object)value[i]);
                    break;
                case TypeCode.String:
                    _writer.Write((string)(object)value[i]);
                    break;
                case TypeCode.SByte:
                    _writer.Write((sbyte)(object)value[i]);
                    break;
                case TypeCode.UInt16:
                    _writer.Write((ushort)(object)value[i]);
                    break;
                case TypeCode.UInt32:
                    _writer.Write((uint)(object)value[i]);
                    break;
                case TypeCode.UInt64:
                    _writer.Write((ulong)(object)value[i]);
                    break;
                default:
                    if (typeof(T) == typeof(byte[]))
                    {
                        _writer.Write((byte[])(object)value[i]);
                    }
                    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(char[]))
                    {
                        _writer.Write((char[])(object)value[i]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException("List type not supported");
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }
```